# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to pass an array from PHP file to JavaScript and store in JavaScript array. Here's the JavaScript code:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
                    nameData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.readyState=4;
            xmlhttp.open("GET","mapPHPname.php?Zip="+zipcode,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$zip=isset($_GET['Zip']);
include 'dbconnect.php';
$sql="Select `name` from doctor where `zip` LIKE $zip";
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
array(name);
if($num_rows>=1)
{
    $count=0;
    while($res_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $name[$count]=$res_array['name'];
    }
}
else
{
    $name[0]="kashyap"; 
}
echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse (< anonymous >)

Comment: what exactly is in the responseText()? Did you try to console.log() it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting some HTML or XML back from the server.

Comment: If there's a `<` at the start, that means your server is sending back an HTML error page.

Comment: This is a textbook example of SQL injection. You can compose custom SQL by tweaking the `Zip` parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

1- You don't declare an array in this way: `array(name)`

Try instead: `$name = array()` or `$name = []`.

2- And quote your include `include 'dbconnect.php';`

3- Correct access to variable `count`, at `$name[count]=$res_array['name'];`, `count` should be `$count`.

And you're not actually looping it. You should make `$count++` after saving to the `$name` array.